# how to create an api in wso2 api manager for the application that is created in mule soft?

Tags: api, wso2, mule, integration, wso2-api-manager

I have created one application in mulesoft, I'm trying to create an api for that application in api manager, can anyone provide the steps for integrating both?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps given in this doc, use your application endpoint as backend while creating the API

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Create+and+Publish+an+API